# Turn a list of strings into a dataframe whilst spilting the string to form the colname and the value

Tags: r

I have a list of strings that contain label names and values.

```
the_list <- c('label1\":15', 'label2\":2', 'label3\":0', 'label4\":1', 'label5\":2')
```

I would like to separate the strings at \": and assign the label to a column and the value as the first entry on this column.

The end result should be equivilent to this:

```
result <- data.frame(label1 = 15, label2 = 2, label3 = 0, label4 = 1, label5 = 2)
```

Ideally the solution can deal with a larger list of strings without much extra brute force.

Interested to hear your thoughts and ideas

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this particular case, `read.dcf` can be of help:

```
read.dcf(textConnection(the_list))
#      label1" label2" label3" label4" label5"
# [1,] "15"    "2"     "0"     "1"     "2"
```

Alternatively, consider just using a standard `data.frame` to store the split data. Here are options with the "tidyverse" and with my "splitstackshape" package:

```
library(tidyverse)
data.frame(the_list) %>% 
  separate(the_list, into = c("label", "value"), convert = TRUE)
#    label value
# 1 label1    15
# 2 label2     2
# 3 label3     0
# 4 label4     1
# 5 label5     2

library(splitstackshape)
cSplit(data.table(the_list), "the_list", "\":")
#    the_list_1 the_list_2
# 1:     label1         15
# 2:     label2          2
# 3:     label3          0
# 4:     label4          1
# 5:     label5          2
```

Or, just use a named vector:

```
setNames(as.numeric(sub(".*:", "", the_list)), sub("\".*", "", the_list))
# label1 label2 label3 label4 label5 
#     15      2      0      1      2
```

Comment: Nice option to do this

Comment: @akrun, thanks. Not sure how robust it would be depending on the OP's actual requirements.

Comment: I was also thinking about similar approach you used. `fread(paste(gsub('"', "", the_list), collapse='\n'), sep=":")`

Answer (score 1):

We can use `strsplit` to split at the `"` and `:`, and `rbind` the `list` elements to a `matrix`.  Then convert the second column to a `list`, set the names of the `lsit` elements with the first column and convert to `data.frame`

```
m1 <- do.call(rbind, strsplit(the_list, '":'))
data.frame(setNames(as.list(as.integer(m1[,2])), m1[,1]))
#  label1 label2 label3 label4 label5
#1     15      2      0      1      2
```